# Spam answer as Low-Quality-review test?

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I just had to review [this test in the LQ queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/496635), which was a spam answer.

However, my thought was that spam should never had appeared in the LQ queue and therefore I was a bit confused about this. I recommended to delete and passed the test, of course, but I thought that maybe this could be an unintended behaviour or bug in the review test algorithm.

Is using deleted spam answers as LQ review test now good and intended, or should it not have happened?

Comment: Well the goal is to see if you are paying attention.. What better than a spam post?

Comment: @Seth Posts that are meant to come up in the LQ queue? If something gets flagged as spam, it should never appear in the LQ queue - or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see why not? It's a good test.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't have to be consistent, the point is catching robo-reviewers. Unless they now make models which detect spam they still serve the purpose.

Comment: Somebody should tag this [tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always been like that: you just never saw a spam question in the review queue before...

That's it! Stop worrying and keep up the good work!

## ;-)